# Errors when testing with PHPUnit 3.5

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, testing, phpunit

After installing phpUnit 3.5 i am trying to run my tests this way:

```
phpunit AllTests.php
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php on line 140
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php on line 140
```

This is the contents of my AllTests.php

And here is the contents of Alltests.php

```
      <?php
    if (!defined('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD')) {
        define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'AllTests::main');
    }

    /**
     * TestHelper
     */
    require_once 'TestHelper.php';

    /**
     * @see SF_Unit_AllTests
     */
    require_once 'unit/AllTests.php';

    class AllTests
    {
        public static function main()
        {
            $parameters = array();

            PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run(self::suite(), $parameters);
        }

        public static function suite()
        {
            $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('EventManager');

            $suite->addTest(SF_Unit_AllTests::suite());

            return $suite;
        }
    }

    if (PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD == 'AllTests::main') {
        AllTests::main();
    }
```

And here is the Unit/AllTests.php file

```
<?php
if (!defined('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD')) {
    define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'SF_Unit_AllTests::main');
}

/**
 * Testhelper
 */
require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/../TestHelper.php';

/**
 * Include unit tests
 */
require_once('unit/Model/ModelAbstractTest.php');
require_once('unit/Model/EventTest.php');
//require_once('unit/Model/UserTest.php');
//require_once('unit/Model/AuthenticationTest.php);

/**
 * 
 * @author jigal
 *
 */
class SF_Unit_AllTests
{
    /**
     * 
     * @return unknown_type
     */
    public static function main()
    {
        PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run(self::suite());
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
     */
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('EventManager Unit tests');
        $suite->addTestSuite('ModelAbstractTest');
        $suite->addTestSuite('EventTest');
        //$suite->addTestSuite('UserTest');
        //$suite->addTestSuite('Authentication')
        return $suite;
    }


}

if (PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD == 'SF_Unit_AllTests::main') {
    SF_Unit_AllTests::main();
}
```

---

TestHelper.php

```
/**
 * Get PHPUnit
 */
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';


/*
 * Set error reporting level
 */
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

/**
 * Default timezone
 */
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/*
 * Set the include path
 */
    /*
 * Set the include path
 */

    $root  = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
    $paths = array(
        "/usr/share/php/",
        "$root/library/Incu",
        "$root/library",
        "$root/tests",
        "$root/application"
    );
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths))

;


defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    or define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
or define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
    require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
/**
 * Autoloader helpers
 */
function _SF_Autloader_SetUp() 
{
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $loader->registerNamespace('SF_');
    $application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/events.ini'
    );

}

function _SF_Autloader_TearDown()
{
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::resetInstance();
    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $loader->registerNamespace('SF_');
}

/**
 * Init autoloader
 */
_SF_Autloader_SetUp();

/**
 * Start session now!
 */
Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
Zend_Session::start();

/**
 * Ignore folders from code coverage etc
 */
//PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addDirectoryToFilter("$root/tests");
//PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addDirectoryToFilter("$root/library/Zend");


PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()->addDirectoryToBlacklist("$root/tests");
PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()->addDirectoryToBlacklist("$root/library/Zend");
```

---

Any Idea's?

**Update**

I have added /usr/share/php to my include path.
Now I am getting a different error:

```
PHPUnit 3.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

....PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 1049

Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 1049
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, actually Laurent Laffont kind of provided the correct answer: incomplete MockObject installation.

Per [Installation Instructions](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/installation.html) you have to uninstall previous PHPUnit, before you will be able to install version 3.5

But that seems not enough, you also have to uninstall extra packages (in this case PHPUnit_MockObjects) and only then install new verstion:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/phpunit
pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_MockObject
pear install phpunit/phpunit
```

And that reinstalled PHP_MockObject package with all necessary files in place.

Comment: Thanks finally got this to work, had to change it to
    pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
though

Answer (score 5):

For PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator error,  had to manually get http://pear.phpunit.de/get/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.0.tgz and copy

```
PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.0/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/
```

to

```
/usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/
```

Comment: my PHPUNit is not installed in this directory. So that won't work

Answer (score 3):

You need to

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php'
```

since phpunit 3.4 IIRC. Do not try to load the individual PHPUnit files anymore.

Oh, and in PHPUnit 3.5 there is an autoloader you should use:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

Comment: Well this gives me a notice that I dont need  to require it anymore. Besides that the errors are not gone.

Comment: Yes that's what I had before. But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see any require_once "PHPUnit/Autoload.php"; code in your question, that's why I didn't see it.

Comment: Its in the testhelper file which was required in one of the files. I have added it to my start post.

Comment: So it seems I was wright about your autoloader:http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/closed#issue/31

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem before the update in my startpost. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I had to do the same thing @Laurent said, it doesn't matter where your phpunit is installed.

If you installed PHPUnit with pear just do a `pear config-get php_dir` in your shell. PHPUnit is most likely installed in that directory.

Wherever your PHPUnit is installed, replace the directory at `PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject` with the directory at `PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/` in the folder you downloaded from here 
 http://pear.phpunit.de/get/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.0.tgz

Comment: Here is a the developer of PHPUnit explaining the problem http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/899-PHPUnit-3.5-Upgrading-Woes.html